# Feasibility of swapping two MacBook Pros (both hard drive and RAM)?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, memory

I have an early 2011 MacBook Pro, and my sister has a mid-2012. I've already seen [the suggested duplicate possibilities](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/33386/85884) that say that just swapping the hard drives shouldn't be problematic, but I've got another layer: I've got 10GB of RAM, an eBay-bought 8GB module and one of the OEM 2GB modules, that I'd very much like to keep.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) says the two generations have different RAM specs - the early 2011 has "1333 MHz PC3-10600 DDR3 SDRAM, Voltage 1.5V" and the mid-2012 has "1600 MHz PC3-12800 DDR3 SDRAM, Voltage 1.35V." I'm going to take an educated guess that mixing frequencies/voltages won't end well, but what if I swapped the pairs of RAM modules? As in, what would happen if I were to put 10GB of RAM designed for early 2011 into mid-2012 and 4GB of RAM designed for mid-2012 into early 2011?

Comment: Nothing would happen, other then the old ones not working, but you can try. The 1333 MHz is just much slower than the 1600.

Comment: @Buscar웃 What do you mean, the old ones not working? I need both computers to be fully functional after everything.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand, are you mixing the old and the new RAM ? If you put faster RAM in a slower machine there is no problem with that, however the opposite might be a problem. means if you have slower RAM  on a faster machine you might see some slowness.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Mixing the two different sets of RAM wasn't my plan, since I think I remember reading things saying that that's a bad idea. I'm planning to take all the RAM currently in the 2011 (1333 MHz PC3-10600) and put it in the 2012, and take the 2012's 4GB of 1600 MHz PC3-12800 RAM and put it in the 2011.

Comment: What do you think is better, 4GB of faster RAM or 10GB of slower RAM?

Comment: I would choose 10 Gig for its size and pay some minor penalty in speed.

Comment: @Buscar웃 One more question: Is there any problem with the fact that the two computers are designed for different RAM voltages?

Comment: It is still the DDR3 family, thus 0.15 Volt should not be an issue, but I am not sure here. That means in order to switch the cell state from 0 to 1 and back one needs 1.5 Volt and the other one needs 1.35 Volt. However from design they can handle up to 1.9 Volt before problems.

Comment: Does your sister know if you are doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The RAM speed won't be a problem, the system will detect the speed of the RAM and run it at the maximum compatible speed. Hard drives also won't be a problem. (you will want to do a "fresh" install of the operating system)

As for the RAM voltage, I think that would be a problem. I'm not completely sure though. Whatever you do, make sure you run the [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) and babysit the machine while its running. Chances are if it passes all the tests, you're good.